# adding new address email and so on in moderncv

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I tried this is  example found in a previous question here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\homepageA}[1]{\def\@homepageA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\homepageB}[1]{\def\@homepageB{#1}}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}%
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageA}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageA}}}%
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageB}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageB}}} }%
  {}{}%
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{aa}{bb}
\homepage{em1}
\homepageA{emA}
\homepageB{emB}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
% arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\end{document}
```

it does not give errors, but the new e-mail addresses do not appear. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The `casual` theme in [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) sets the email addresses in the footer (as part of `\makecvfooter`), not the title (in `\maketitle` or `\makecvtitle`). I've updated the [etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch to correct the addition in the footer below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\homepageA}[1]{\def\@homepageA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\homepageB}[1]{\def\@homepageB{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makecvfooter}% <cmd>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}}% <search>
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageA}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageA}}}% <replace>
   \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepageB}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepageB}}}}%
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{aa}{bb}
%\homepage{em1} Not needed
\homepageA{emA}
\homepageB{emB}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still not working; I copied and paste your code but still produce the following error:


  (/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 \makecvtitle
                 
? 


Seems that i can not do any modification in moderncv

Comment: @Cesare: My suspicion is that you have an outdated TeX distribution. What do you have? You may find some relevant help in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: Hi, I have texlive 2010 (i'm a mac user); however, the same error append also with lualatex and  the version for ubuntu 12.04 precise (after updating all the packages, in order to be sure that latex was updated), but the problem persist (same error code).
Are those version outdated?

Comment: @Cesare: TeX Live 2010 is old, since 2013 is currently available, with 2014 being released shortly. I am running with [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) 2013/04/29 v1.5.1. See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)

Comment: I updated to texlive 2014 now and works, thanks. May be it was too old. Strange that neither with lualatex works, theoretically should be newer

Comment: Conversely now I have another problem: I redefine the makecvtitle for the classic one of adding another address; the problem is that even thug i specify only one telephone number, the symbols of all the telephone number appear. This happens bot if y give the mobile with \mobile{9999999} as if i give with \phone[mobile]{9999999}.

I used Werner example were a second address called address two is specified.

How can i fix it?

Comment: @Cesare: I don't understand. If it's different from this post, ask a new question.